# Different results for %%GLOBAL_ProductID%% and 'actual' product ID - Bigcommerce - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

I am working on a project where I need to reference an unchanging attribute of a product (an item on the site).  In the past I have referenced them using the value of an attribute called "data-product".   This value is the ID of the product that has been assigned to it by Bigcommerce, so it will never change.  Yesterday I discovered the global product_id variable (%%GLOBAL_ProductID%%) so I did a few tests.

When I take the value of the product ID variable and print it to the console:

```
<span id="the-id-of-the-product">%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%</span>
<script>       
  var theProductIdNumber = $.trim($('span#the-id-of-the-product').text());
  console.log(theProductIdNumber);
</script>
```

I get a different number then when I inspect the same product and look at the value of the 'data-product' attribute:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Even more confusing, I found one case where the value for %%GLOBAL_ProductID%% what the same number (string) for two different products.

Can you tell me why this is happening?  I assumed that using the BC defined global variable would be a more solid method of referencing the product, since thats kind of what it seems like it's for.

As always, your time and help is much appreciated, and I hope you all have a nice day.

Comment: Hi Tron, in what file are you inserting and printing the `%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%`? I've never seen this issue occur before, and usually this global can always be trusted. The 100% sure way to know a product's ID is to get it from the backend.... If you log into the control panel, go to `View Products`, and go to edit any of the products, you will see its ID in the URL bar of your browser. Example: `store.com/manage/products/2264/edit`

Comment: Can you provide a specific link to where this error can be reproduced?

Comment: @root In this case I put the script on the product page, as in, you click a product form a category, and it takes you to the description page for that product (product.html).

Comment: Yes @root I know where to get (what should be) the ID of the products, it's just that the value of this variable is never the same as the 'real product id', and since product ID is the only unchanging  piece of information for a product, It's really the only variable I can use, otherwise I am hardcoding descriptions (or something similar) and it can break, needs to be maintained more, etc..

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post but I had the same problem today and believe I understand what is going on.

My JavaScript was referencing GLOBAL_ProductId at the bottom of the product.html template. The value was never correct and was also unchanging. Looking deeper, I noticed that it always seemed to be the ID for the last product shown in the Related Products region.

I took the JavaScript variable initialization out of product.html and moved it to ProductDetails.html and the problem was solved. It looks like when the Related Products region is generated, someone decided to recycle the Global_ProductID variable. Or...something like that, yuk.

Your theme may not even include a ProductDetails.html, but if you tinker around with where you initialize variables that reference GLOBAL_ProductID, that might square you away.